# Facebook not seeing correct image for sharing

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-sharer

When sharing, for instance this post: http://www.birddartmouth.co.uk/candlelit-dartmouth-friday-saturday-festive-weekend-look-forward-welcoming/, Facebook doesn't seem to recognise the correct image.

In the header, I have this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.birddartmouth.co.uk/wp-content/themes/html5blank-master/img/logo.png">
```

But that thumnail doesn't show up when sharing.

Does anyone know how to get Facebook to recognise the correct image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force a Facebook cache refresh with this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Enter the URL for your site and click 'debug'.  This will force a re-scrape.